# .Net WMI <Blah>ChangeEvent to monitor directories

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm trying to monitor USB SD-Card Reader insert/removal, the goal is to watch mounted directory.

code sniplet looked something like this, the major difference is the query:

```
mWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
mWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
mWatcher.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 OR EventType = 3");
```

1. with `Win32_DeviceChangeEvent`: I can monitor USB plug/unplug, but when the reader is inserted with no SDCard, the event triggers, but the mount point is invalid. If I then insert a SDCard to the reader, no event is triggered.
2. with `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent`: The event triggers when the mount point is a drive letter (for example, `F:\`). But if the mount point is a directory (something like `C:\usb_reader\`) instead of a drive letter, this event doesn't trigger.

is there an event that's triggered when the mount point changes?
for example, when something is mounted/unmounted to/from `C:\usb_reader`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need to reinvent the wheel, someone has already done similar project: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program)

Usage is exactly what you needed:

```
{
     DriveDetector driveDetector = new DriveDetector();
     driveDetector.DeviceArrived += new DriveDetectorEventHandler(OnDriveArrived);
     driveDetector.DeviceRemoved += new DriveDetectorEventHandler( OnDriveRemoved);
     driveDetector.QueryRemove += new DriveDetectorEventHandler(OnQueryRemove);
}
```

You can check the source code if interested.